# How to publish a post with multiple attachments to a user's facebook profile?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

My facebook app uses the Facebook C# SDK to publish to a user's Facebook profile. I'm currently publishing multiple posts with one attachment, but I'd much rather publish one summary post with multiple attachments. I've done this with the [JavaScript API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui), but is it possible with the C# SDK?

This is my current publish code:

```
FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp(user.AccessToken);
string userFeedPath = String.Format("/{0}/feed/", user.FacebookUserId);

string message = String.Format("{0} earned an achievement in {1}",
                               user.SteamUserId, achievement.Game.Name);
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.link = achievement.Game.StatsUrl;
parameters.message = message;
parameters.name = achievement.Name;
parameters.description = achievement.Description;
parameters.picture = achievement.ImageUrl;

app.Api(userFeedPath, parameters, HttpMethod.Post);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We currently don't support multiple attachments. As far as I know you can't publish multiple attachments with either the graph or rest api. If you have a sample that shows how to do it, I will get it implemented in the SDK.

Comment: There are docs for the stream.publish method of the old rest api - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/. It references the attachments docs - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments. There isn't a full sample, but hopefully it's enough. I haven't been able to find anything on multiple attachments with the graph api (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/). Awesome library by the way!

Answer (score 0):

i have the same code as yours but it doesent work for me. I am trying this:

```
public void plesni()
{
    try
    {
    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
    parameters.message = "xxxxxxx";
    parameters.link = "xxxxxxxx";
    // parameters.picture=""
    parameters.name = "xxxxxx";
    parameters.caption = "xxxxxxx";
    parameters.description = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    parameters.actions = new
    {
        name = "xxxxxxx",
        link = "http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com",
    };
    parameters.privacy = new
    {
        value = "ALL_FRIENDS",
    };
    parameters.targeting = new
    {
        countries = "US",
        regions = "6,53",
        locales = "6",
    };

    dynamic result = app.Api("/uid/feed/", parameters, HttpMethod.Post);
  //  app.Api("/uid/feed", parameters);
        Response.Write("Sucess");
    }
    catch (FacebookOAuthException)
    {
        Response.Write("...... <br/>");
    }
}
```

if instead of uid I put me it works fine.
I am hoping for your help.
Have a good day.

Comment: I'm instantiating the FacebookApp object with the user's offline access token, which I don't see in your code sample. You'd have better luck getting an answer if you create a new question.